# Flex Items not on the same height

Tags: html, css

my problem is, that I have a `<ul>` und it is `display:flex`
And I want all items from this flex-container to be on the same height.

Here is a fiddle of my problem : https://jsfiddle.net/01cwok4L/

Notice that the `<h2>` is slightly below the `<a>`-tags and the `<input>`

Comment: Actually, it exactly the same height. You'll see this if you inspect the element. Your issue is `line-height`, you should do some research to see how this affects text. A `line-height` of 1 will (kind of) fix this issue.

Comment: .flex-h2 {
    padding:7px;
    margin-top: -1%;
} Add that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add line-height to your H2:

```
h2 {
   line-height:16px;
    margin: 0;
}
```